# Sample K representative frames within a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, photos, signal-processing

I have an image-based processing module that takes photos for some computer vision processing. I have many videos, but I need to sample representative frames as its inputs, preferably those frames with higher attention.

What are some good and effective algorithms or approaches to take K sample frames in a video? Interesting feature is that usually camera doesn't move much in successive frames with higher attention. So basically we have more stable scenes when a person is focusing on something important. Is there any ways to take this into account for our samlping?

Comment: ffmpeg has a [thumbnail](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#thumbnail) filter whose purpose is to "*Select the most representative frame in a given sequence of consecutive frames*". What it does is calculate the avg histogram of an interval of frames and select the frame whose histogram is nearest to the avg. one.

Comment: @Gyan Do you have a reference for how thumbnail really work? Those histogram and such?